# Change TRUE and FALSE to Verdadero and Falso in "mchoice" exercises of R-exams

Tags: r, templates, r-exams

I want change TRUE and FALSE to "Verdadero" and "Falso" in  "mchoice" exercises of R-exams.

In which template should I do it?

Comment: ifelse(condition, "Verdadero", "Falso")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
answerlist(ifelse(solutions, "Verdadero", "Falso" ))
```